# How to see application logs in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In tests I am making an api call, which returns 400. It is expected, but I can't find a way to debug this. Does django keep logs in a file somewhere? Or can I enable showing logs please?

```
res = self.client.post(self.url, data=payload, format='json')
print(res)

// <Response status_code=400, "application/json">
```

I knot something went wrong but how do I debug the server?

Thanks

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Now I realised that it was giving me the output of the __str__ method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `response.content` to view the final content/error messages that will be rendered on the web-page, as bytestring. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.content)

```
>>> response = c.get('/foo/bar/')
>>> response.content
b'<!DOCTYPE html...
```

---

If you are returning a json response(which you probably are if using rest framework), you  can use `response.json()` to parse the json. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.json)

```
>>> response = client.get('/foo/')
>>> response.json()['name']
'Arthur'
```

**Note:** If the `Content-Type` header is not `"application/json"`, then a [**ValueError**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) will be raised when trying to parse the response. Be sure to handle it properly.